# Twilio Connection decline with code: 31002

Tags: android, twilio

All,

I'm trying to implement Twilio in an Android app using the Quickstart Guide listed on the site. I can get the call to connect successfully, but about 10 secs after connecting, the connection disconnections and calls this method:

```
@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection connection, int i, String s) {
    D.debugClass(getClass(), "disconnected code: " + i + " status: " + s);
}
```

The error printed out is: `disconnected code: 31002 status: Connection declined`

I'm using the `server.py` file from the Twilio example, and I've put it up a heroku server.

The server logs indicate that my /call endpoint was successful and returned a 200. I believe the `ACCOUNT_SID`, `APP_SID`, and `AUTH_TOKEN` are all correct.

I've also added this line `Twilio.setLogLevel(Log.DEBUG);`, and the logs from Twilio don't indicate an error. I'm not sure where to look next?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?